# problem with installing nodejs on kali linux

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can not run the configure script `./configure` for installing nodejs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./configure", line 19, in <module>
    from distutils.spawn import find_executable
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.spawn'
```

Comment: Are you trying to use Node.js for pentesting (fine), or are you using Kali as a general-purpose/daily-driver Linux distro because you think it's cool (not fine)?

Comment: How is that related to the question?

Comment: @FatihAktaş Because this is almost certainly an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/386992). See also [Pounding A Nail: Old Shoe or Glass Bottle?](https://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/408925), which I feel like this question leans towards, and [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/217726) for what's wrong with using Kali that way.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
sudo apt install python3-distutils -y
```

taken from [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/30189#issuecomment-548250793)

Answer (score 0):

If you run into a `No module named 'distutils.spawn'` error when executing `./configure`, please try `python3 -m pip install --upgrade setuptools` or `sudo apt install python3-distutils -y`.

For more information, see `https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/30189`.